# Why widget.pack(side=Left) puts new widget to the right?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

(old title: How to properly delete cavas item?)

My proplem is that everytime i want to load a new image onto my canvas and delete the old one it puts the new image beside the space where the old one was before. 
My code looks like this:

```
def load_to_canvas(fname, canvas):
    img = Image.open(fname)
    canvas.imgph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    l = Label(canvas, image=canvas.imgph)
    l.photo = canvas
    l.pack(side=LEFT)
```

I tried various options like putting one of these on top of the load_to_canvas function:

```
canvas.delete('all')
canvas.get_tk_widget.delete('all')
l.pack_forget()
```

or setting the variables to nothing.

My Canvas is declared with these functions:

```
def create_canvas(self, canvasframe):
    canvasframe.canvas = Canvas(canvasframe, width=200, height=200)
    canvasframe.canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
    return canvasframe.canvas

def create_canvasframe(self):
    canvasframe = Frame(self)
    canvasframe.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4,
                        padx=0, sticky=E+W+S+N)
    return canvasframe
```

As you will probably see, I am quite new to Tkinter. My problem, to be specific, is that the old picture is deleted, but the new one not put on top of it, but next to it.

**EDIT:**
I found the problem. It is the packing of the label (last line in 'def load_to_canvas' ) to the leftmost space. Somehow even after deleting the old image the leftmost position for the new one was still right of the old one. Changed it to an absolute position with 'grid.(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W+S+N)' and it works fine.

That makes the problem i asked for in the headline not accurate anymore, so I changed it. I hope thats fine.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Are you wanting to draw an image within the space of the canvas?

Further:  When you say "i want to load a new image onto my canvas and delete the old one", -- is it further then, that you want to create something like an animation, or a mouseover, or a checkbox clicking on and off -- is the new image within the canvas supposed to completely replace the prior, in its place?

Comment: The program (canvas) is just supposed to show a picture. And when a new picture is loaded (via open file dialog), it is supposed to replace the old one. The old picture is not necessarily to be deleted, just to disappear. But just 'overpainting' the old picture is not working (new one appears next to old one), hence my thought that a deleting command is required. I will try Bryans suggestion after work...